# tab menu, delay when clicking through tabs... jquery fix to show loading msg if load time over 1 sec?

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering if anyone knows a fix for this.

I have a tab menu and when you click between tabs sometimes there is a delay in the page opening, - the difference can be from m/s to about half a minute - so i tried to add in a loading message for the pages that seemed to take a while.

I thought i had solved it by adding in the message when a tab was clicked

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
 {
    jQuery('#loading').hide();
    jQuery('.tabmenu a').click(function(){
    jQuery('#loading').show();
 });
});
```

but on pages that previously took about 1 sec to load now take at least 5.

What i really need to do is something like

if tabmenu clicked and page takes longer than 1 second to change then show 'loading' message.

Is it possible to do this? Any help greatly appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: My first question is why it takes so long to begin with. Are you making an AJAX call, or just hiding and showing different divs? If just hiding and showing, then there is no way it should take so long. You should show us more of your code, including the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$('.tabmenu a').click( function(event) {
  window.clearTimeout(window.timeOutId);
  window.timeOutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
      $('#loading').show();
  },1000); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the tabs are loading up slowly, it must mean you are doing it with the AJAX concept. Now the question is, are you doing it correct -- jQuery. If you are doing this with jQuery, probably with [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function, then you could easily make it better:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "exmaple.php",
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#loading').show();
    },
    success: function (){
        $('#loading').hide();
    }
});
```

Further more:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tabmenu a').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "exmaple.php",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            success: function (){
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This should be the most accurate and relay only on the `example.php` pageload speed. That means, if you want to make your application faster, then you should optimize the back-end.